# How to use spservice for taxonomy terms in metadata administration

Tags: managed-metadata, spservices

I have added terms in termset and need to loopthrough the terms in javascript to get the array of terms. so i used spservice. but not working

```
 function GetTerm() {
   var termStore = document.getElementById('<%=TermStoreID.ClientID=%>').value.toString();
    var termSet = document.getElementById('<%=TermSetID.ClientID %>').value.toString();
    var name = new Array();
   var index = 0;
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetChildTermsInTermSet",
        sspId: termStore,
        lcid: 1033,
        termSetId: termSet,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
           alert("ok");
        }
    });
    return name;
}
```

not even the alert message is displaying

Comment: what are you trying to do? There might be better solutions...

Comment: i need to get the terms in the term set and store in array.

Comment: Are you certain the termStore and termSet variables comes back with the correct guid?

Comment: the guid is correct but the service is not triggerring.

Comment: I need to query out all the 1st level terms of a termset and store in array. Did you fix your code? Could you give me an example if possible?

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it, you need to do some debugging. If "the service is not triggerring", there is likely an error of some sort.

First check to make sure your references to jQuery and SPServices are correct (this causes a suprising majority of first time issues). See my post [Adding jQuery+SPServices to a SharePoint Page: Step One, Always](http://sympmarc.com/2011/07/08/adding-jqueryspservices-to-a-sharepoint-page-step-one-always/).

Assuming that your references are good, add `alert(xData.responseText);` in the completefunc to see what's returned from the Web Service call.

M.